# Why is google chrome blocking my pdf in iframe

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, iframe

I have an iframe with a `src` attribute set to a https pdf link. On firefox (99.0.1), my iframe displays correctly the pdf, but not on google chrome (101.0.4951.54). I have no extension installed on my google chrome, and found no errors or any logs in the console.

Chrome gives me a grey iframe like that:
[image]
(in english it says "This page has been blocked by Chrome")

I've went into the console, inside the network tab and here is the only useful information I've found:
[image]

Comment: Same issue here. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue but only on CodePen, which is displaying everything in an iframe, which was probably causing problems.

Once I created my own html file, everything was working correctly.

Both codes work correctly:

```
<embed
  class="pdfobject"
  type="application/pdf"
  title="Embedded PDF"
  src="https://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf"
  style="overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
```

and

```
<iframe src="https://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf" width="500" height="375" />
```

Alternatively, you can used PDFObject package - "An open-source standards-friendly JavaScript utility for embedding PDF files into HTML documents."
https://pdfobject.com/